# Only return Unique values with Join and Filter functions

Tags: arrays, join, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-query

I have an elaborate data set for motorcycle parts. I am trying to create a year, make, model table based on data from multiple sheets.

Here is my function in the destination Google Sheet:

```
=JOIN(",",FILTER('YMM Handlebars'!H:H,'YMM Handlebars'!A:A=A8))
```

Because of the amount of data, I'm running into the issue with this error:

```
Error
Text result of JOIN is longer than the limit of 50000 characters.
```

I can get the character count of Join down if I can remove duplicate values being returned from the Filter. I've tried these two approaches, but neither have resolved the duplicate value issues:

```
=JOIN(",",UNIQUE(FILTER('YMM Handlebars'!H:H,'YMM Handlebars'!A:A=A8)))
=JOIN(",",FILTER(UNIQUE('YMM Handlebars'!H:H),'YMM Handlebars'!A:A=A8))
```

Any ideas on how to resolve? Thanks in advance for taking a peak and your time.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

you can subdevide your ranges:

```
=JOIN(",", FILTER('YMM Handlebars'!H1:H1000,    'YMM Handlebars'!A1:A1000=A8))&","&
 JOIN(",", FILTER('YMM Handlebars'!H1001:H2000, 'YMM Handlebars'!A1001:A2000=A8))
```

---

or not use `JOIN`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY(IF('YMM Handlebars'!A:A=A8, 'YMM Handlebars'!H:H&",", ), 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0),, 9^9))
```

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(UNIQUE(FILTER(TRIM('YMM Handlebars'!H:H)&",", 
 'YMM Handlebars'!A:A=A8)),, 9^9))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @player0 , appreciate the time. The Array Formula might work, but it's not returning only unique value. So snippet of result is:

Model_XL 1200CP, Model_XL 1200CP,
Model_XL 1200CX ROADSTER (LM),
Model_XL 1200T SUPERLOW 1200T,
Model_XL 1200T SUPERLOW 1200T

... So I need to make sure they are returning unique values only

Comment: @dbp can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: sure thing, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1daJb-0uJuMoxEHVR_hnMUmMFR69WnUSLUPh5upAvtxM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: ughhh, sorry. try this https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1daJb-0uJuMoxEHVR_hnMUmMFR69WnUSLUPh5upAvtxM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @dbp answer updated. use 3rd formula to get all uniques